# Token get node NID

Tags: tokens

Can anyone please tell me how to get the NID of a node from the 7.x-1.7 version of the Token module?

I haven't used Token in a long while until now when I'm simply trying to include the NID in the file directory path of an image field.

As the following screen shot shows, I have no token representing the NID (there used to be quite a lot of current node tokens):

[image]

Help, please!

Comment: What is this being used for? Instead of checking under "Current Page", look under "Node". I believe the token, if my memory serves me, is "[node:nid]".

Comment: Do you have a node context? If you are using this in a block (or other entity), it might be unaware of  the rest of the page and as such does not have access to `[node:*]` tokens.

Comment: There is no node context so [node:*] does not exist.

Comment: I assume you  need to add the relationship 'node' to your view.Then you will be able to access the node token.

Comment: @danuddara: Views has nothing to do with this. The question is about Tokens

Comment: [current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:1]  will this work? https://www.drupal.org/node/1360922

Comment: @danuddara: THANK YOU a thousand times. 3/4 days on and you've saved the day. Much appreciated. IF YOU POST IT AS AN ANSWER, I'LL BE HAPPY TO MARK IT TO YOUR CREDIT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:1]` is the way to get the node ID from the URL with the token module. [Source](https://www.drupal.org/node/1360922).

<sup>Glad it helped you out sisko. Cheers! Thank you.</sup>